# Dynamically addition of rules to validationengine allrules

Tags: jquery, rules, jquery-validation-engine

I have validation of controls with using jquery plugin jquery.validationengine.js. It has rules. I common these rules satisfied me... but also we have some rules stored in db. Is it possible to add dynamically rules from db to existing rules of jquery.validationengine.js?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you'll just need to have your server-side scripting language write the javascript so it can be included dynamically before being sent to the browser.

Comment: thanks - it is clear  - even for reason to fetch data from db - I use C# and ASP.NET - but what jquery code is to add these rules?